# How to map nested Property with Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper

I am trying to map Student with StudentDto, this is what I am doing but it is complaining about the nested property which is of type `List<StudentContact>`

Both the objects, StudentDto and Student have exactly the same properties, this is what i am using to try to map the objects.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration( 
                    cfg => cfg.CreateMap<StudentDto, Student>());                
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            var driverActivationResponse = mapper.Map <List<Student> > (studentDto);// "studentDto" is List<StudentDto>
```

my classes

```
public class StudentDto
    {
        public StudentDto()
        {
            if(StudentContacts==null) StudentContacts=new List<StudentContact>();
        }
        public string Id { get; set; }   
        public List<StudentContact> StudentContacts { get; set; }

    }

    public class Student
    {
        public Student()
        {
            if(StudentContacts==null) StudentContacts=new List<StudentContact>();
        }
        public string Id { get; set; }   
        public List<StudentContact> StudentContacts { get; set; }

    }

    public class StudentContact
    {
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryContactNo { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: How is it *complaining*? An exception message is what we need.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help to specify the source collection type and destination collection type in your `Map` call?

```
var driverActivationResponse = mapper.Map<List<Student>, List<StudentDto>>(studentDto);
```

---

It looks like the AutoMapper code you have is correct. If you're still getting an error, something else must be wrong. Perhaps your `studentDto` is not really a `List<StudentDto>`?

In any case, here's an entire example that works without error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using AutoMapper;

namespace ConsoleSandbox
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(
                cfg => cfg.CreateMap<StudentDto, Student>());
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            var studentDtos = new[]
            {
                new StudentDto
                {
                    Id = "1",
                    StudentContacts = new[]
                    {
                        new StudentContact { ContactName = "Dan", PrimaryContactNo = "123" },
                        new StudentContact { ContactName = "Stan", PrimaryContactNo = "456" },
                    }.ToList()
                },
                new StudentDto
                {
                    Id = "2",
                    StudentContacts = new[]
                    {
                        new StudentContact { ContactName = "Foo", PrimaryContactNo = "789" },
                        new StudentContact { ContactName = "Bar", PrimaryContactNo = "101112" },
                    }.ToList()
                },
            }.ToList();
            var driverActivationResponse = mapper.Map<List<Student>>(studentDtos);
            Console.WriteLine($"Contacts Count: {driverActivationResponse.Count}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class StudentDto
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public List<StudentContact> StudentContacts { get; set; }

        public StudentDto()
        {
            if (StudentContacts == null) StudentContacts = new List<StudentContact>();
        }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public List<StudentContact> StudentContacts { get; set; }

        public Student()
        {
            if (StudentContacts == null) StudentContacts = new List<StudentContact>();
        }
    }

    public class StudentContact
    {
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryContactNo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Shax, please see my edited answer. I've added a complete code sample that works. Hopefully it will lead you to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This should help -

```
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Student, StudentDto>()
           .ForMember(a => a.StudentContacts, b => b.ResolveUsing(c => c.StudentContacts));

        var map = Mapper.Map<StudentDto>(new Student
        {
            Id = "100",
            StudentContacts = new List<StudentContact>
            {
                new StudentContact{ContactName = "test",PrimaryContactNo = "tset"}
            }
        });
```

you cannot map like `mapper.Map <List<Student>>(studentDto);`. The top level member cannot be a list when using automapper.

Comment: giving error at this line  "var map = Mapper.Map<StudentDto>(new Student"

Comment: what? use `AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<>`. May be you didn't refer `AutoMapper.dll` in the `using` declaration.